# Uploading/Synching Files to a Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I'm using SharePoint 2007 and SharePoint Designer and I'm looking for a way to automate uploading files.  We have a system that generates reports and emails them out to the department, but we would rather they be automatically uploaded to a sharepoint library.  The easy way to do it would be to enable incoming emails for the sharepoint server, but I was told that was not an option.

From what I have been told, the files can be auto-saved to a unix or windows directory, so if there is a way to synch a directory with a document library that seems like it would be the easiest option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to go a different direction with this.  We are downloading the files into a common directory that is used by both UNIX and Windows.  From there a batch file is run to move the files to a mapped directory that points to a SharePoint library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an easy way to automatically sync folder contents to a SharePoint list, except in the case you don't need any permission trimming on the reports. In this case, you could copy the files directly to the layouts folder (well, a sub-folder specific to your project name). You'd still have to come up with a way to display the files. I'm not sure if there are SPD components you could use to list/show files in a folder. This would not let the user interact like a true list though and would not allow permission trimming very effectively.

Personally, being a developer, I'd go the route of writing a console app or service to receive the report (or scan a pick-up directory) and upload the files to a specific list using either the Object Model (requires app to run on the SharePoint server) or via the SharePoint Web Services (can be run from anywhere, usually has minor permission-related headaches to get working.)